# Combining Two Working Scripts no longer works. Bookmarklet to send Text Message to Mobile

Tags: javascript

### Two Scripts work fine separately, but combined do not.

**Description:** I'm building a bookmarklet to copy selected text to the clipboard, then send it via gmail to a mobile via SMS message.

- The code to make the dropdown selector for the operator works fine.
- The code to send the selected text via Google → SMS works fine.

I've tried combining the two working codes into a single bookmarklet. 
Here it is on CodeSandbox (almost working...):

[Bookmarklet to send selection to SMS via Gmail](https://codesandbox.io/s/1yk41069wl)

## 🤔

Here is the working dropdown:
[Dropdown Form Bookmarklet](https://codesandbox.io/s/o4yrm80965)

Here is the working Messenger Service:
Test it on CodeSandbox (working fine):

[Send SMS Text via Gmail](https://codesandbox.io/s/xlxk94rj34)

```
function getOperator(){
for (var i = 0, length = ops.length; i < length; i++)
{
 if (ops[i].checked)
 {
  mobOperator=(ops[i].value);
  return mobOperator;
  }
 }
}
function sendIt(){
popw='';
Q='';
d=document;
w=window;
if(d.selection){
Q=d.selection.createRange().text;
}else if(w.getSelection){
Q=w.getSelection();
}else if(d.getSelection){
Q=d.getSelection();
}
var recip=document.getElementById('numero').value; var recip=recip.split('-').join(''); var recip=recip.split(' ').join(''); var recip = recip.replace(/[()]/g,'');   popw=w.open('http://mail.google.com/mail/s?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to='+ recip +'@'+ getOperator()+'&su='+encodeURIComponent(d.title)+'&body='+encodeURIComponent(Q)+escape('%5Cn%5Cn')+encodeURIComponent(d.location)+'&zx=RANDOMCRAP&shva=1&disablechatbrowsercheck=1&ui=1','gmailForm','scrollbars=yes,width=680,height=575,top=175,left=75,status=no,resizable=yes');
if(!d.all)setTimeout(function(){popw.focus();   
},50); 
};
```

Comment: Check this out: https://v83r01163y.codesandbox.io/

Comment: Dang that was fast! AWESOME!

Comment: The script now works fine except for one thing... I'm still scratching my head over.

Now it's not putting the selected text into the body of the email... it all looks fine to me... somehow the handoff seems to hang...

  
````
`console.log("DWERE", d.selection, w.getSelection());

    if (d.selection) {
      console.log("here1");
      Q = d.selection.createRange().text;
    } else if (w.getSelection) {
      console.log("here2");
      Q = w.getSelection();
    } else if (d.getSelection) {
      console.log("here3");
      Q = d.getSelection();
    }`
````

Comment: Drag & Drop version of the bookmarklet may be found here: https://codepen.io/bookmarklets/pen/MLxoJJ